# Verificar se existe arquivo se existir relatar PYTHON Blibioteca > .os

Tags: python

Verificar se a pasta já não existe, se existir, deverá imprimir uma mensagem ao usuário indicando.

Eu fiquei preso sem saber como conferir em algo relacionado a isso :

```
os.listdir()
os.mkdir (input('Insira o nome:'))
if os.path.exists ('Users\Akros\Desktop\TESTE') == True:
  print ('Ja existe um arquivo com esse nome!')
else:
  print ("Criado com sucesso!")
```

O erro que aparece é :

```
File "C:\Users\Akros\Desktop\TESTE\OS.py", line 21, in sys_calls
os.mkdir (input('Insira o nome:'))
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Não é possível criar um arquivo já existente: 'AKROS'
```

Já usei os.path.isdir / os.path.isfile / os.path.lexists .

Isto e um requerimento de um exercício que estou fazendo do instituto federal, caso http://charles.garrocho.com/SO2016/documentos/trabalho_pratico_1_so.pdf no caso esse requerimento ele pede para que se for criado ou deletada uma pasta que já existe ou não existe avisar o usuário . Mas não consigo descobrir qual comando ou a logica de como executar isso, ele nao vai pro " print " aparece a mensagem de erro.

Comment: Qual a versão do seu python? no python2.x o `input` requer uma entrada no tipo numérica, para inserir texto tem de ser o `raw_input`

Comment: No instituto eles recomendam a gente a usar o python 3.5 Nunca cheguei a usar o 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que estás a tentar criar o diretorio logo nesta linha:

```
os.mkdir (input('Insira o nome:'))
```

E ele lança a excepção (esse aviso/erro), porque já deve existir. Devias ver primeiro se existe antes de criar, ficando assim:

```
import os.path

diretorio = input('Insira o nome:')
if os.path.isdir(diretorio): # vemos de este diretorio já existe
  print ('Ja existe um arquivo com esse nome!')
else:
  os.mkdir(diretorio) # aqui criamos o diretorio
  print ("Criado com sucesso!")
```

NOTA, que todos os metodos que usou são para coisas diferentes, no final das contas é verdade que todos verificam a existência de algo. Mas:

```
if os.path.isdir(path):  # Verifica se e diretorio
   ...

if os.path.isfile(path): # Verifica se e ficheiro
   ...

if s.path.exists(path): # verifica se existe, seja ficheiro (arquivo), ou diretorio
   ...
```

Tem de ajustar um desses ao seu caso. Outra coisa, pelo aviso que dá ('Ja existe um arquivo com esse nome!'), vejo que pode estar a tentar criar um ficheiro e não um diretorio, se for o caso troque estas duas linhas:

```
if os.path.isdir(diretorio):
...
os.mkdir(diretorio)
```

Por

```
if os.path.isfile(diretorio):
...
ficheiro = open(diretorio, "w") # criamos/abrimos o ficheiro
#.... .... ... operacoes no ficheiro
ficheiro.close()
```

Comment: E que eu pesquisei na biblioteca OS para tentar resolver mas as informações estavam meio difíceis de entender. E no exercício eu tenho que criar um diretório mover renomear e deletar. Caso qualquer uma das opções não seja disponível por ele não existir ou já existir tem que ser relatada. Por isso eu não sabia qual das 3 opções usar.
E qual a logica para checar se já tinha alguma das alternativas

Comment: Eu nao tenho reputação para agradeçer a sua resposta, mas ela me ajudou a terminar obrigado.

Comment: Nada ainda bem que ajudou

Comment: Consegui a reputação e dei um up kk

Comment: Se for diretorio é como fiz em cima no código completo