# Verificar se existe um arquivo dentro de um diretório específico

Tags: python

Tenho várias arquivos dentro de um diretório chamado `imagex`, cerca de umas 5.000 imagens.

Um exemplo simples de um arquivo:

```
file_path = "C:/imagex/jonsnow.png"
```

Como passo verificar, de maneira eficiente, se existe uma imagem específica dentro desse diretório?

Comment: Relacionado e talvez duplicado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/133366/verificar-se-existe-arquivo-se-existir-relatar-python-blibioteca-os

Comment: @Miguel acho que não procurei direito, não tinha visto essa pergunta ai.

Comment: Tranquilo, sem problema, de qualquer maneira a resposta desta vai mais direita à questão

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes fazer o seguinte, usando [os.path.exists](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists):

```
import os

file_path = "C:/imagex/jonsnow.png"
if os.path.exists(file_path):
    # existe seja arquivo ou diretorio
```

Para verificar somente ficheiros podes fazer:

```
...
if os.path.isfile(file_path):
    # existe e e ficheiro
...
```

Comment: Funfou aqui! =) tks

Comment: De nada @AckLay ainda bem